# how to change postition of digits in an integer in c

Tags: c, function, codeblocks, swap, digits

The problem is as follows: 
I need to write a function that takes a four digit integer and then encrypts the number in this manner: take each digit and replace it by (c + 7)% 10;
and then swap the first digit with the third and the second with the last digit;
and then returns the encrypted integer.
I have managed to write this much of code thus far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 100


int encrypt(int a){
  int n=0,i;
  for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    n = a%10;
    a = a/10;
    n = (n+7)%10;
  }
}


void main()
{
  int a;
  printf("Enter the four digit integer: ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  encrypt(a);
}
```

I am getting correct output for the conversion but I have no idea how to swap the position of digits.

Comment: note: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: wait!! `for (i){}`???? what?

Comment: never mind that wrote it and forgot to remove it @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: i use void main not int main

Comment: Ah, and when going to clean this up, please also indent your code properly.

Comment: It is not your's to use the signature of `main` you want, but the language's and the execution environment's. `void main()` is an invalid signature. A proper compiler with warnings (**always do it**) enabled should complain.

Comment: *i use void main not int main* That's like saying, "I use red for go and green for stop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be:

```
int encrypt(int value) {

    int first = value / 1000;
    int second = (value / 100) % 10;
    int third = (value / 10) % 10;
    int fourth = value % 10;

    first = (first + 7) % 10;
    second = (second + 7) % 10;
    third = (third + 7) % 10;
    fourth = (fourth + 7) % 10;

    return third * 1000 + fourth * 100 + first * 10 + second;
}
```

Comment: @Cherubim No, a good program is one that's easy to understand.  Up to a point, having fewer lines can make things easier to understand, because there's less to understand.  But past that point, cramming everything together just makes things harder to understand, and is not in any way "good".

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
int encrypt(int num) {
    int arr[4];
    int i = 0;
    arr[0] = (num / 1000);
    arr[1] = (num / 100) % 10;
    arr[2] = (num / 10) % 10;
    arr[3] = num % 10;
    for (; i < 4; i++) {
        arr[i] = (arr[i] + 7) % 10;
    }
    return arr[2] * 1000 + arr[3] * 100 + arr[0] * 10 + arr[1];
}
```

Comment: but if I use an array I cannot then return it while I am obliged to do so (which is returning the final encrypted number ).

Comment: @AliHaroon I have return an integer at the end.

Comment: nice method actually never thought of combining the usage of an array and integer gonna try it now thx :)

Comment: there is only one problem when the zero is the last number in the encrypted number it is not shown in the output @Yashwanth Reddy

Comment: The leading 0s are omitted when printing integers.

Comment: @user3121023 Sure leading zeros can be printed, why not print even more, say a hundred? Ok, common practice does no print leading 0's in integers. But again this is not really encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by taking an array this way:

```
int encrypt(int a)
{
   int i,x[4];
   for (i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      x[i]=((a%10)+7)%10;
      a=a/10;
   }
    return x[2]+(10*x[3])+(100*x[0])+(1000*x[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each digit is represented by 4 bits.
so you can use bit-shift operator to move digists as per your requirement.

n << 8 should move your first digist to the place of third digit

secDig = ((num >> 4 ) & 0x0F) will give your second digit

now secDig << 12 should move your second digit to last [ie 4th digit]

Hope it helps.

so the simple answer is to use bitwise operators << [left shift  ], >> [right-shift] and & [ bitwise AND] properly.

Hope it helps

Comment: forgot to mention, you should use bitwise OR to reasseble these shifted digits to make the new 4 digit number you need.

Comment: C does not use [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Answer (score 0):

A slight addition to Aleksandar Makragić's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641556/1083414) to take into account the leading zeroes when the return value is <1000, e.g. input: **1234** => output: **0189** or input: **3333** => output: **0000**:

```
 printf("Output:\t%04d\n", output);
```